# Post body empty despite setting extended to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a form that submits data, but the data when handled using express in the app.js file returns an empty array.

App.JS:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const Person = require('./models/Person')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  const newInfo = req.body
  console.log("Logging new data")
  console.log(newInfo.emailAddress)
  res.render('post')
})
```

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: <form method="post" action="post">

Comment: Could you be more specific? Did you use a tool like postman or insomnia? Likely you attached the body to the wrong parameter for the request. Your using the `urlencoded` which isn't the standard way to include data nowadays.

Comment: I guess that maybe there is no element with name `emailAddress` in the `form`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I used a form group using bootstrap. I then submitted the information using the form and then console.logged() it.

Comment: I also tried sending a request using postman incase there was some issue with my form, but the body still seems to be returning an empty array.